# For which values of $r$ and $s$ does $ \int_{0}^{2} \frac{(1+x)^r-(1+x)^s}{x^2} dx $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

My guess is that **r** and **s** need t be large enough to make sure that the numerator is bigger, in a sense, than **x**, in order to ensure that the denominator has an x with a power that is smaller, in a sense, than 1, in  $$ \int_{0}^{2} \frac{(1+x)^r-(1+x)^s}{x^2} dx. $$ I find it very difficult, to make this precise though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near $0$, we have

$$(1+x)^p=1+px (1+\epsilon(x)) $$
with $$\lim_{x\to0}\epsilon (x)=0.$$

thus your function is equivalent to

$$\frac {r-s}{x} $$
the integral is divergent.
it converges only if $r=s $.